# Differences between φρονεω and νοεω

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek, word-choice

What is the difference between the meaning of these two words? How is it different when I φρονεω vs when I νοεω?

So far as I understand it, νοεω is from the νους or καρδια, and φρονεω is from the φρην. But even these terms seem hard to distinguish.

Is it that νοεω means I think with my mind, while φρονεω means I think with my soul?

I welcome any help or suggestions. If there are some specific references in Classical literature that define these terms or help illuminate their distinction by putting them in close proximity, please share.

Comment: Are you looking for technical usages (e.g. Aristotle's) or the common usage? Even philosophers have their own conventions: Aristotle uses φρόνησις for "practical reason" (sometimes translated "prudence") whereas νοῦς can refer either to "intellect" in general or the grasp of immediate principles. Plato doesn't seem to have the same "practical" restriction on φρόνησις.

Comment: Common usage, but I imagine the philosophical use is informed by or helps inform the common usage.

Comment: [Here](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*f%3Aentry+group%3D47%3Aentry%3Dfrone%2Fw) & [there](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*n%3Aentry+group%3D26%3Aentry%3Dnoe%2Fw), with usage illustrations.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I already checked LSJ... I made my post because LSJ (and other resources) don't clarify the actual difference between these two words... I also realized my question also relates to νοος and φρην. I think these need to be properly understood to understand the verbs.

Comment: LSJ just lists the same glosses. That's the point of making this post. It says "to be minded" or "to think" for both of them. Okay... but what does that actually mean? What is the ancient Greek understanding of these words?

Comment: As I understand it now... φρονεω is the action of using the φρην, which is the mind located in the midriff/diaphragm/stomach. It involves a kind of thinking that comes from oneself, from the soul or will. Whereas νοεω is from the νοος, which is the mind located in the ητορ/καρδια, and is a kind of intellectual/reasoning. Taking outside thoughts in and reasoning with them. Thoughts?

Comment: @Phillip That's generally correct. It can take some times to write up a careful analysis, but considering the verbs in terms of φρήν or νόος is good for understanding their origin, less so for understanding their later development. Ancient Greek of course recorded well over a thousand years of literary history, so it can be difficult to disentangle all the various meanings inherent in the word to their metaphorical developments later on.